# What happens if I hook my Latitude e6410 1400x900 to an LCD at 1400x1080

Tags: display

Looking to get an external monitor for my Latitude but don't know how it will look based on the laptops 1400x900 res.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you extend the desktop, both screens <s>will</s> might run at 1400x900.

If you make it run only on the external monitor, it will look fine at 1400x1080

Comment: why would extended desktop not let you have different resolutions on the displays?  Is there something specific to the graphics in this machine?  (DUPLICATED desktop, naturally, would have the same res).

Comment: @Shinrai - That's been my experience w/ extended desktops - whether it was a limitation of the driver, monitor or other external factor - I don't know. Feel free to edit /post a rebuttal :)

Comment: I'm not familiar with this particular model, but unless the graphics are limited for some reason there's no reason it shouldn't work just like a desktop under Windows - that is, display resolutions are completely independent of one another.  You should be able to run the internal at 1400x900 and the external at 1400x1080.  Again, I'm unfamiliar with this machine but I don't see any reason a business class notebook from a major OEM shouldn't be able to do this.

Comment: and @Shinrai I've been able with my laptop to display at differing res when connected to an external and using the internal... the issue may be the video car itself or drivers... it's possible either way...

Comment: I should have read my video card manual ;) Resolution is device dependent if the card supports the res.